# ERPNEXT Data Export Fail

Tags: export, erpnext, frappe

I have ERPNEXT version 15 on my host.
The data is not exported to another language such as AZ and redirect to //mysite.com/api/method/frappe.core.doctype.data_import.data_import.download_template. Then show Internal Server Error in sales invoice list module

I expect it to download the Excel file like the rest of the lists.